# Class instance fields are undefined when assigned from parent class constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand the dynamics of why the following solution [doesn't work](https://playcode.io/697217/) in the case where a class field is assigned from parent's constructor:

```
class B{
  constructor(val){
        this.a = val;
    }
}

class A extends B{
  a;
  constructor(val){
    super(val);
  }
}
```

With the above calling `new A(1)` will return an instance whereas `A.a` is `undefined`.

If assignment is done via a named `function` rather than super `constructor` the implementation [will work](https://playcode.io/697224/):

```
class B{
  assignMe(val){
        this.a = val;
    }
}

class A extends B{
  a;
  constructor(val){
    super(null);
    super.assignMe(val);
  }
}
```

This correctly sets `A.a = 1`.

Here you have a [more complex implementation](https://playcode.io/697224/) which represents my real-world use scenario.

Why can't I achieve this by using `constructor`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? On the face of it, having the superclass assign to a property that the subclass declares is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in my real-world scenario it does not assign to subclass properties. Even if `class B` contained the field `a`, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: It does if `B` has `a` and `A` doesn't, which is what you'd expect if `B` is responsible for initializing `a`.

Comment: If you look at what Babel does with that code, *after* the `super()` call, the property "a" is initialized to `undefined` in the A constructor. That's the semantics of having A define the property instead of B.

Comment: https://playcode.io/697224/  this is a real world scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it happens is that by declaring the `a` property in `A`, you're *replacing* the `a` property with a new one when `A`'s constructor reaches the point it has access to `this` (just after the call to `super()`). It's as though you'd written this code in the constructor (hand-waving some details):

```
class A extends B {
    constructor(val) {
        super(val);
        Object.defineProperty(this, "a", {
            value: undefined,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}
```

You can find details about that (the `[[Set]]` vs. `[[Define]]` design point) in [the public fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#public-fields-created-with-objectdefineproperty).

You've said that in your real code, `B` has the `a` property *as well* as `A` having it. The solution is to remove the declaration of `a` from `A` so it uses the one that `B` initializes in the constructor:

```
class B {
    a;
    constructor(val) {
        this.a = val;
    }
}

class A extends B {
    constructor(val) {
      super(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Constantin - Thanks! My suggestion for the linked code would be the same as the above: Declare `a` in `BaseModel` and not in `A`.